# "..., not less so."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english

Here is a sentence I found in the official guide to the TOEFL iBT test.

> Well, I personally think that the Great Depression of the 1930s actually makes this more understandable, not less so.

I found this sentence in a listening script, and I was wondering the meaning of "not less so". Did the speaker say this to express his opinion that the Great Depression makes something more understandable? Is it grammatically correct? Do Americans really talk like that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the author is opining that the Great Depression of the 1930s makes this more understandable.
2. Yes, this sentence is grammatically correct. "So" may be considered a [pro-adjective](https://www.yourdictionary.com/proadjective) (a word that stands in for a "normal" adjective, in this case "understandable"). We can interpret this in at least two ways:

- The adjective phrase "not less so" is in apposition to the adjective phrase "more understandable". Appositives are usually nominal phrases, but sometimes they consist of other constituents. This is perfectly acceptable.
- Commas often replace coordinating conjunctions, so this comma could be replacing "and".

3. Yes, Americans do really talk like that. It's quite normal (although some people might omit "so").